# python return duplicates in list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, duplicates

How do I find list of duplicates from list of strings? 
clean_up function is given

```
def clean_up(s):
""" (str) -> str

Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. 

>>> clean_up('Happy Birthday!!!')
'happy birthday'
>>> clean_up("-> It's on your left-hand side.")
" it's on your left-hand side"
"""

punctuation = """!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r"""
result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
return result
```

Here is my duplicate function.

```
def duplicate(text):
""" (list of str) -> list of str

>>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
'James Gosling\n']
>>> duplicate(text)
['james']
"""

cleaned = ''
non_duplicate = []
unique = []
for word in text:
    cleaned += clean_up(word).replace(",", " ") + " "
    words = cleaned.split()        
    for word in words:
         if word in unique:
```

I am stuck in here..
I can't use dictionary or any other technique that keeps a count of the frequency of each word in the text.
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here:

```
cleaned += clean_up(word).replace(",", " ") + " "
```

This line adds the new "word" to a growing string of all words so far. Therefore each time through the `for` loop, you recheck all words you have seen so far.

Instead, you need to do:

```
for phrase in text:
    for word in phrase.split(" "):
        word = clean_up(word)
```

This means you only process each word once. You may then need to add it to one of your lists, depending on whether it's already in either of them. I suggest you call your lists `seen` and `duplicates`, to make it clearer what is going on.

Comment: Good points. To be fair to the OP though - `clean_up` only removes leading/trailing commas (and other puncutation)... It seems that a `re.findall('\w+', text)` would be a more appropriate tokenizer, but that's up to the OP. The OP may also wish to consider using sets if possible, rather than lists.